# Replace suffix/ending on the Product name in query for grouping

Tags: string, t-sql, replace

In our database system we have some products that have the same name but have different endings.

Examples:

```
                            2012    2013
Produkt namn xyz ab 2002    0       2
Produkt namn xyz cd 2004    5       3
Produkt namn xyz ef 2002    2       1
Produkt namn xyz gh 2006    3       0
```

We would like to group them under one name.

```
Produkt namn xyz           10       6
```

We have created an query or stored procedure which is the source of a report. I used the REPLACE function to group similar products but in this case it is to many different so it would be useful to use wildcard with REPLACE like this:

```
REPLACE(product_name, 'Product name xyz%', 'Product name xyz')
```

Then we could group similar products under one product name.

Unfortunately it does not work that way.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to solve it?

EDIT:
Perhaps I was unclear. We have a lot of different products with different names and different length of the names.

New example list:

```
                            2012           2013
                            units sold    units sold
Produkt namn kkkkkkk mmmm     7            9
Produkt namn xyz ab 2002      0            2
Produkt namn xyz cd 2004      5            3
Produkt namn AAAAA MMMM NN    6            8
Produkt namn xyz ef 2002      2            1
Produkt namn xyz gh 2006      3            0
Produkt namn ABC 123 anything 4            9
```

Find this part (Produkt namn xyz" cd 2004") of this particular product and replace with nothing to group them under one name for summary.

```
Produkt namn xyz             10            6
```

My code so far:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[uspOnAndOffTrade]
    (
        @PeriodStart AS INT
    ,   @PeriodEnd AS INT
    ,   @CurPerStart AS INT -- Ny 140510
    ,   @PrePerEnd AS INT -- Ny 140510
    ,   @PreYr AS INT = NULL
    ,   @CurYr AS INT = NULL
    ,   @FamiljTyp AS INT = NULL
    ,   @ProdNo AS INT = NULL
    ,   @ProdDescr AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,   @ProducentName AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,   @CustomerName AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,   @Land AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    ,   @Region AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    WITH qAllTradeSumTot
    AS (
    SELECT     pt.InvoDt
                ,  REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(p.Descr, 'Product Name xxx 12345', 'Product Name xxx 750 ml'),
                'Product Name 2004', 'Product Name'), 'Product Name 2002', 'Product Name')  AS 'Product'
                , p.Inf AS 'Producent'
                , a.Nm AS 'Customer', p.Gr4, a.R9, 
                    p.R8 AS 'Familj', pt.PrTp, p.ProdTp4, 
                          dbo.ProdCat.Descr AS 'Land', ProdCat_1.Descr AS 'Region', 
                          p.R8, pt.TrTp, 
                          CASE WHEN p.Gr4 = 0 THEN CAST(ROUND(SUM(pt.NoInvoAb * 1), 0) AS INT) 
                          ELSE CAST(ROUND(SUM(pt.NoInvoAb * p.Gr4), 0) AS INT) END AS 'SumU', LEFT(pt.InvoDt, 4) 
                          AS 'Yr'
    FROM         dbo.ProdCat INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Prod AS p ON dbo.ProdCat.PrCatNo = p.PrCatNo INNER JOIN
                          dbo.ProdTr AS pt ON p.ProdNo = pt.ProdNo INNER JOIN
                          dbo.ProdCat AS ProdCat_1 ON p.PrCatNo2 = ProdCat_1.PrCatNo INNER JOIN
                          dbo.Actor AS a ON pt.CustNo = a.CustNo
    WHERE     ((a.R9 = '1') OR (a.R9 = '2'))
            AND (pt.Price <>0)
            AND (pt.InvoDt BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PeriodEnd) 
            AND (@FamiljTyp IS NULL OR p.R8 = @FamiljTyp)
            AND (@CustomerName IS NULL OR a.Nm LIKE '%' + @CustomerName + '%')
            AND (@ProdNo IS NULL OR p.ProdNo = @ProdNo)
            AND (@ProdDescr IS NULL OR p.Descr LIKE '%' + @ProdDescr + '%')
            AND (@ProducentName IS NULL OR p.Inf LIKE '%' + @ProducentName + '%')
            AND (@Land IS NULL OR ProdCat.Descr LIKE '%' + @Land + '%')
            AND (@Region IS NULL OR ProdCat_1.Descr LIKE '%' + @Region + '%')
    GROUP BY pt.InvoDt, p.Descr, p.Inf, a.Nm, p.Gr4, a.R9, p.R8, pt.TrTp, 
        LEFT(pt.InvoDt, 4), p.ProdTp4, dbo.ProdCat.Descr, ProdCat_1.Descr, pt.PrTp
    )
    SELECT ats.Producent, Product,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PrePerEnd) AND R9 = '1' THEN SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [OffTrade1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @CurPerStart AND @PeriodEnd) AND R9 = '1' THEN SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [OffTrade2],

        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PrePerEnd) AND R9 = '2' THEN SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [OnTrade1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @CurPerStart AND @PeriodEnd) AND R9 = '2' THEN SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [OnTrade2],

        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PrePerEnd) THEN ats.SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [Tot1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @CurPerStart AND @PeriodEnd) THEN ats.SumU ELSE 0 END) AS [Tot2]

    FROM qAllTradeSumTot AS ats
    GROUP BY Producent, Product
    HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PrePerEnd) THEN ats.SumU END) >= 0 )
    OR (SUM(CASE WHEN (InvoDt BETWEEN @CurPerStart AND @PeriodEnd) THEN ats.SumU END) >= 0)
    ORDER BY Product;
END
```

Hope it is clearer now!

Thanks for all your help!

Kind regards
/martin

Comment: Use update.. Not replace like this `update table set column=pp where column like [p]% select pp sum(col1),sum(col2) group by pp`

Comment: To be clear, I'm using "product line" to reference the shortened name you wish to group by, and "product name" as the more specific name. Is there a way to differentiate the product line from the product name? is there a table of product lines? If there are, please provide a sample schema and data, as it will help people here provide a workable answer.

Comment: They're not trying to update a table they're trying to group values by a part of the value name. Have you tried a simple LEFT statement in your grouping?

Comment: To Jaaz Cole: No. Sorry. This is not a well-formed database. Not so well defined. /martin

Comment: Hello. If you have different grouping names for different products then a would suggest you have two approaches: either, add a grouping name column to your product table and retrieve it and group on it as in my example below, or add a productname_productgroup table and join to that and group similarly. 
Note that the productname_productgroup could be a simple TABLE variable within your stored proc if you are concerned for any reason about adding or changeing tables within your database. Again my answer below should help.

Comment: By the way your nested Replace statements is a really bad approach, not least because it is very hard to understand - I had to run a few examples to see what it was doing - it also has the disadvantage of being really inflexible if you need to add any more products and groupings. Abandon that approcah and use the grouping column or table as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my comment - Have you tried a simple LEFT statement in your grouping? Here's an example, I've used a table variable to provide some test data.

```
DECLARE @X AS TABLE ( product varchar (50))

INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('xx abc 1')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('xx abc 2')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('xx abc 3')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('xx def 1')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('yy abc 1')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('yy abc 2')
INSERT INTO @X (product) VaLUES('zz abc 1')

SELECT LEFT(product, 6) AS leftbit, COUNT(*)
FROM @X
GROUP BY LEFT(product, 6)
```

results

```
leftbit   Column1
xx abc    3 
xx def    1 
yy abc    2 
zz abc    1
```

Comment: Hi. As you can see in my edited question above I do not think it will work because we have names of different lengths so the string handel probably can not be done that way. Nevertheless, thanks! /martin

Answer (score -1):

```
select 'Produkt namn xyz', sum(units2012), sum(units2013) 
  from table
 where left(name,16) = 'Produkt namn xyz'
```

Comment: How do you want me to elaborate my explanation of my problem? What is unclear? Why are my post worth a Down vote? 
When you see my addition of the code above, can you show me how to use your solution in my code? Thanks for your reply. /martin

Comment: At the time I posted the posted question was "Find this part (Produkt namn xyz" cd 2004") of this particular product and replace with nothing to group them under one name for summary.
Produkt namn xyz             10            6"